# How do i create a formula for three consequective YES?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to make a formula that when i have 3 consecutive cells in the same row with the value of YES to collor for the three cells in the same color?
I have a sheet where i have a goal for a client, and the person taking the data just selects from a drop down list YES or NO, I want when he/she select YES in E8, F8,and G8, then these three cels turn to blue or red or green. So that i know this target is mastered. And i want the rest of the cells in the same row to be locked so data is not collected after reaching mastery criteria.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VNFi.png)

Comment: What determines the color?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: my rows are from E8 until AS8. each cell has a list from data validation YES or NO. for an example, if E8 is Yes, F8 is YES, G8 is YES. I want E8, F8 and G8 to be conditionally formated in RED, and the next cell in the same row H8,I8,J8,K8 until AS8 to be dark black to indicate that you should not write values in them.

Comment: i have been searching for this for months. if someone knows please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for the first part (coloring cells with 3 consecutive YES). For the second part about locking cells, I don't think it is feasible without VBA.

Here is what I did: [Screenshot Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNqwR.png)

I assumed you have 8 columns with YES/NO answers in 3 rows in`B3:I5` and that cells `B1:I1` contains the rank of answer (1 to 8). Columns J and K need to be empty.

**1. Put a formula in cell `L3` to get the rank of the first YES in a row of 3 YES, then pull the formula down**

Here is the formula:

```
=SMALL(IF((IF(B3:I3="YES",B$1:I$1,0)+1=IF(C3:J3="YES",C$1:J$1,0))*(IF(C3:J3="YES",C$1:J$1,0)+1=IF(D3:K3="YES",D$1:K$1,0))=1,B$1:I$1,99999),1)`
```

*Explanation*: `SMALL(IF(...),B$1:I$1,99999),1)` is to get the rank of the first YES that is from a consecutive series of 3 "YES". If there is no serie of 3 YES, 9999 is returned.

The idea to capture the rank of YES from series of 3 is:  if 3 YES are consecutive, then: A) the rank of the first YES +1 is equal to the rank of the second YES, and B) the rank of the second YES + 1 is equal to the rank of the third YES.

We check condition A for the 8 answers: If B3:I3={NO,YES,YES,YES,NO,YES,NO,NO} and cell J3 is empty, then:

- `IF(B3:I3="YES",B$1:I$1,0)`   returns {0,2,3,4,0,6,0,0}.
- `IF(B3:I3="YES",B$1:I$1,0)+1` returns {1,3,4,5,1,7,1,1}.
- `IF(C3:J3="YES",C$1:J$1,0)`   returns {2,3,4,0,6,0,0,0,0}.

So `(IF(B3:I3="YES",B$1:I$1,0)+1=IF(C3:J3="YES",C$1:J$1,0)` will return an array for the 8 answers: {FALSE,**TRUE**,**TRUE**,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE} => The answers number 2 and 3 satisfy condition A.

We check also this for condition B, and do a product of the TRUE/FALSE array to know the rank of the answers which satisfy both conditions.
After this, we use function SMALL() to get the first YES.

**2. Put conditional formatting in cell B3 with the formula below and extend to other cells (B3:I5).**

This will format the cell only if the rank of the answer is equal to the rank of the first YES in `L3`, or to the rank of first YES +1, or rank of first YES+2.

```
=IF(OR(B$1=$L3,B$1=$L3+1,B$1=$L3+2),TRUE,FALSE)`
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/0fP38ym  this is a screen image. i am not sure why it did not work. could you please look at the cells and let me know how the formula should be adjusted! i am really really really grateful.

Comment: Hey, do you mind putting the screen image with the regular stackoverflow website (https://i.stack.imgur.com/) ? If not possible in a comment, can you maybe edit your question and add it in there? Thanks

Comment: i added in the question a screen image.

Comment: Thanks! I think there is a small adaptation error in your formula, I would replace by `=SMALL(IF((IF(E15:AS15="YES",E$13:AS$13,0)+1=IF(F15:AT15="YES",F$13:AT$13,0))*IF(F15:AT15="YES",F$13:AT$13,0)+1=IF(G15:AU15="YES",G$13:AU$13,0))=1,E$13:AS$13,99999),1)`

Comment: Thank you! what about the conditional formating formula?

Comment: You just have to adapt the one I gave in my answer to your document. My B1 is your E13, and my L3 is your AV15.

Comment: i am not sure why it is not working on my end.

Comment: Do you know where the problem occurs? To have an idea, you can start by creating a conditional formatting rule for cell E15 with formula `=IF(OR(E$13=$AV15,E$13=$AV15+1,E$13=$AV15+2),TRUE,FALSE)`.  Then test if the rule works: put "YES", "YES", "YES" in `E15`, `F15` and `G15`. Normally cell `AV15` should have a value of 1 (as the rank of the first YES of a 3-YES series is 1) and cell `E15` should color. You can perform some other tests to see if coloring works well for `E15`. After that, you can edit the rule so that it applies to `E15:AS15` (if it still works, try `E15:AS30` or beyond).

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlzalameh: did it work or did you find where the problem was coming from?

Comment: I have not been able to check, i will check and let you know as soon as i can. Thank you for following up.